# Real Analysis Egorov's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to use Egorov's Theorem in a proof. However, I only have convergence in measure of f_k to f and uniform integrability of f_k. How can I combine these two to get convergence point wise so that I can use Egorov?

Thank you so much for your help!